# Is it possible to parse a PowerShell param block by using a regular expression

Tags: regex, powershell

I search for a regular expression to extract a Powershell param block from a complete PowerShell script.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
     [string]$computerName,

     [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
     [string]$filePath
    )

...
```

A colleague means that it is not possible to parse this structure by using a regualr expression. He said regular expressions can't count the opening and closing signs (...) inside the param block and that makes it impossible to parse the param block.

Comment: I'm sure its possible but it would be a complex regex with a lot of escaped characters. What have you tried and what output are you ultimately trying to achieve?

Comment: See [.NET regex reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_3): you can use balancing group constructs. However the correct approach is to use AST parser ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42548383/3959875))

Comment: Is there a particular reason _why_ you're even contemplating using regex here instead of just using PowerShell's parser?

Comment: I was recently contemplating the same thing (from the looks of your sample, pretty much the same thing really). But in the end I just decided to use another meta comment for that: `# param: computer, path` for each script. Much easier to extract, more flexibility elsewhere…

Answer (score 1):

Good news: your colleague is wrong.
It is true that a *simple* regex has issues with nested data, but that is only true if you have **unlimited level nesting**.
This is explained very nicely in this question: [How to match string within parentheses (nested) in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17759264/7586)

In your case, even a simple regular expression can work:

```
(?:\[[^\]]+\]\s*)*\$\w+
```

[Working example](https://regex101.com/r/gpvqyB/1)

This finds `$parameters` with blocks of `[attributes]` before them. There is very little nesting involved. This is a naive regex, and it fails if you have comments, strings with brackets, etc. But the regex can be expanded to support these cases.

Some more points:

- Practically, of course [a parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42548059/extracting-the-function-body-from-a-file-using-powershell/) is better.
- Advanced regular expression engines have features like [recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17845034/7586) or [balancing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17003799/7586), which make even unlimited-level matching possible.
- You want to make sure you are not matching elsewhere in the text, for example inside a string or on commented text. I've mentioned similar edge cases here: [Why it's not possible to use regex to parse HTML/XML: a formal explanation in layman's terms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6752487/7586)

Comment: Your example doesn't cover default value of optional parameters

Comment: @Clijsters - Right! of course it doesn't, it is not meant to be a complete example. I did say "This is a naive regex, and it fails if you have comments, strings with brackets, etc. But the regex can be expanded to support these cases". This is a *theoretical* is-it-possible question, not a practical one.